How to use group_vars or host_vars when playbooks are in a subdirectory in Ansible AWX
I need help configuring group_vars and host_vars in Ansible AWX when playbooks are in a subdirectory and not in the root directory.
Here is my directory structure:
inventory/
  group_vars/
    all/
       all.yml
  inventory
playbooks/
  test_group_vars.yml
ansible.cfg

It only works, if I put my group_vars under the playbooks dir.
AWX does not find the variables either in group_vars or inventory/group_vars.
I have seen multiple "best practice" project structures with group_vars inside an inventory subdir.
Is it possible to put group_vars/host_vars outside of my playbook folder for AWX?
Do I need to set playbook_dir or playbook_vars_root?
update:
This is also mentioned here:
https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/15438

gourp_vars and host_vars can be in either the inventory directory you specify or in the playbook directory (playbook_dir), just mind that they do have a different level in the precedence: see numbers 6, 7 and 9, 10

Yes, everything works fine with Ansible on CLI, but Ansible AWX ignores group_vars and host_vars if I put them in my root or inventory directory.

AWX and AAP work fine when you split the inventory/inventories in separate git repositories, apart from your "project" which has the playbooks. On the command-line Ansible configuration file can be used to define roles_path and inventory. Implicitly collections/requirements.yml and roles/requirements.yml are used to pull in dependencies.
